# Fluent NHibernate CompositeId trying to insert null values

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent, composite-id

I am working to map an existing database using Fluent NHibernate and have encountered a problem when it comes to complex many-to-many relationships (additional columns).

I know that many-to-many relationships with additional columns have to be mapped as `HasMany` rather than `HasManyToMany` as they are not pure many-to-many relationships. The linking table has to be mapped as a class within itself, which I have done in the example below.

When loading this data from an existing database it loads fine. The project I am working on takes this data and inserts it into an empty database, which is where the problem occurs. I think that when inserting into the new database the `CompositeId` is trying to insert `NULL` values for `ItemID` and `ItemGroupID` which is not allowed in the database. Changing the database structure is not a viable option at this point, is there a way around this issue?

Thanks, example code below.

---

### Entity Classes

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual long ItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemGroup
{
    public virtual long ItemGroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ItemInGroup> ItemsInGroup { get; set; }
}

public class ItemInGroup
{
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemGroup ItemGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

### Mapping Classes

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        Table("Items");
        Id(x => x.ItemID).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class ItemGroupMap : ClassMap<ItemGroup>
{
    public ItemGroupMap()
    {
        Table("ItemGroups");
        Id(x => x.ItemGroupID).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.ItemsInGroup).KeyColumn("ItemGroupID").Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class ItemInGroupMap : ClassMap<ItemInGroup>
{
    public ItemInGroupMap()
    {
        Table("ItemsInGroups");

        CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.Item, "ItemID")
                     .KeyReference(x => x.ItemGroup, "ItemGroupID");

        Map(x => x.DisplayOrder);
    }
}
```

Comment: is `ItemInGroup.Item/ItemGroup` correctly initialised? Is DisplayOrder the only property in the link table?

Answer (score 0):

assuming DisplayOrder is the only extra column in the link table why not use the List index of IList as order?

```
public class ItemGroup
{
    public virtual long ItemGroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class ItemGroupMap : ClassMap<ItemGroup>
{
    public ItemGroupMap()
    {
        Table("ItemGroups");
        Id(x => x.ItemGroupID).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.ItemsInGroup)
            .Table("ItemsInGroups")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ItemGroupID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ItemID")
            .AsList("DisplayOrder")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```